# SolidJS: "SyntaxError: Importing binding name 'FileRoutes' is not found"

Tags: typescript, browser, solid-js

I receive this error from the browser having installed `solid-start` with `npm I solid-start`.

I created the project initially with `npx degit solidjs/templates/ts-tailwindcss my-solid-project`

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "vite-template-solid",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prettier": "2.8.7",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "typescript": "^5.0.3",
    "vite": "^4.1.1",
    "vite-plugin-solid": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@solid-primitives/resize-observer": "^2.0.15",
    "p5": "^1.6.0",
    "solid-js": "^1.6.10",
    "solid-start": "^0.2.26",
    "vite-plugin-solid-svg": "^0.6.1"
  }
}
```

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

Never come across this error before...I copied the `root.tsx` content directly from the SolidStart site:

```
import { Body, FileRoutes, Html, Routes } from "solid-start";

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Body>
        <Routes>
          <FileRoutes/>
        </Routes>
      </Body>
    </Html>
  );
}

export default Root;
```

I see the export it is complaining about is a function:

```
// solid-start/index.tsx
export declare function FileRoutes(): JSX.Element;
```

Any ideas?